# Is it possible to cluster data into 100% right groups by using k-means?

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I am using k-means and Euclidian distance algorithm to cluster data (iris.csv).
However, I cannot cluster all of them into the right groups, there are some data within the wrong group.

So, I just would like to know that is it possible to cluster all the data into the right groups 100% ?

Another question in my mind is what is the best criterion to choose k?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically use of clustering algorithms is when you don't actually know what is the right group for the given set. Even if your algorithm does cluster all the data from a given training set correctly that still won't mean it will cluster **any** data correctly. Moreover you should try to avoid overfitting to example data as this usually decreases performance.

As for choosing k - there are several algorithms and the best one may vary depending on the problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

K- means had a tendency to create equally sized, convex clusters. If your clusters are of very different sizes or have irregular shapes some other algorithm may have better performance. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Clustering_algorithms